# VBA PivotTable ShowDetail writing into array

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a PivotTable with 5 thousand rows. For each row, I need to know their detailed positions. I can use the ShowDetail method, but it's not exactly what I want. It's created a new sheet for each row.

Is there a way to extract details of a row into a variable without creating new sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no workaround without creating a new sheet, but you may use something like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim r As Range, rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim pivotSheet As Worksheet

' define some sheet to work on
Set pivotSheet = ActiveSheet

' disable screen blinking and notifications
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' show details of some range
Range("your range").ShowDetail = True

' assign details to variable
' details were alwawys shown to me
' as a selected range
Set rng = Selection
i = 1

' do stuff with details
For Each r In rng
    pivotSheet.Cells(i, 5) = r.Value
    i = i + 1
Next

' delete details sheet so none can see it
rng.Parent.Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```